# How can I access the current URI in python's mako templating system?

Tags: python, pylons, mako

I'd like to submit the form to the current URI, like this:

```
<form action="${CURRENT_URI}" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
```

from within a mako template.  But I am not sure what variable holds the current uri information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
```

If you leave the action empty, it will be posted to the current url.

However, if you need the current url for some other reason, it can be retrieved by calling `pylons.url.current()`